# jQuery File Upload - Why the selected file's name is being translated?

Tags: jquery

I'm using the http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/ plugin. After I select the file in the file dialog box, I see its name is translated on the upload list (try by yourself on that demo site, I've selected the `Meduza.jpg` file and on the list it is the `Jellyfish.jpg`). How to turn off that translation ? I want to have the original file name.

[image]

### Edit.

I've contacted with this plugin author, he says that I probably have a browser add-on installed or another plugin in my webpage which is responsible for this behavior. I'm using the FF 14.0.1

Comment: I have tested on many file through my computer and don't found anything wrong.Which one you talking about please clear it then I will make you sure.

Comment: I don't have any problem with file name in the demo.

Comment: Some plugins change the file-name regarding with reason for the functionality they gave. Best thing you can tried is run Firefox in safe-mode which make all plugin Disabled (s0 you can make yourself sure)

Comment: I've run the FF in safe mode and the file name was also translated

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's sounds both weird and funny! :)

Seriously, I'm not aware about any translation unless you specify it. I tried to upload image demokritos.jpg and I got demokritos.jpg (not aristoteles.jpg).

I also tried to upload file called Meduza.jpg and I got Meduza.jpg.

Are you really sure, there's nothing else behind it?

Comment: Nop,e even if the FF is in the safe mode

Comment: Could you try to upload other files with different filenames?

Comment: I've tested it on the standard Win 7 pictures. Look at the screenshot

Comment: All right, let's localize that problem. Could you please try it in another browser, like IE, google-chrome, etc? I'm using google-chrome/linux and everything works well. Are you sure that you browser don't translate any language automatically? Eg: google-chrome tends to translate other than your own language and could it do even without telling you about it (if you allowed him to do so). Maybe the translation is just 'on the screen', but the file is uploaded with the same filename (as I would expected)

Comment: I've also tested in the IE 9 and Chrome. The same situation. The uploaded file has also the translated name

Comment: I have the info about the Firefox 14 on Mac OS X doesn't make that scenario

Comment: In that case, the problem could be somewhere in your Win 7, but I don't know this OS, so I'm not able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is really simple the real name of the file is in english.  The windows os show you a localized file name.  Try the same file on a different machine with a different localization or in any other browser and the real filename will always be in english.